# Can you get the Len() of a Screen flow text area?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am trying to get a character count of a user input on a screenflow.

I would like to use this on a validation for the screen flow and check that the number of characters does not exceed 255.

When I try LEN({!variableName}) it returns 0. When I put the {!variableName} into the error message, it returns the entire string (Well over 700 characters.) I am confused on how this variable is populated with data but will still show 0 length. Is this because the variable is not assigned data when the validation checks?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with this today, and this is how I handled it.

I created a Screen Element and added a Long Text field to it, without any validation, just the field and nothing crazy so far.

[image: Creating Screen Element]

Next I created a Formula that calculated the length of the field.

[image: Let's make a formula]

Now comes the fun part, I created a Decision that says, "If the formula is over 700, go back to the original Screen Element"

Here is the Decision logic

[image: Decision details]

Here is how the flow should look when you update the decision destinations.  Reminder, the "Too Long" decision path goes back to the original Screen Element.

[image: Final flow layout]

After you set this up, go back to the Screen Element and add some Display Text using the formula you created earlier.

[image: Display Text details]

Add some visibility parameters to this Display Text as well

[image: Visibility parameters]

As a final note, ensure that you set the default text of the field your validating as the value from the field you're validating (in my example it's {!Field_to_Validate_Length})

Viola, here is your finished product

[image: Too wordy!]

Answer (score 2):

`LEN()` doesn't support Text Areas in general, which is might be why it's not working. As an alternative, you try creating an invocable aAex snippet that uses the `length()` method of the [String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm). You would need to do something funky like validate outside of the screen and then display another screen to the user if it's too long, but that should work.

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but it does support (see below) I was able to add this to a long text area. I'm sorry, I haven't been around this long to see when this feature wasn't actually working for Long Text Area fields

[image]